# Change boolean var onClick based on parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a page that sets a variable to true or false based on a button click. This is doable if I create a function per variable/button, but since there will be quite a few variables in the end, I would like to do this in a single function, if possible:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" id="colorbutton" class="button red" onClick="manualSelect('Color')">Colors</button>
  <button type="button" id="animalbutton" class="button red" onClick="manualSelect('Animal')">Animals</button>
</div>
```

```js
$manualColor = false;
$manualAnimal = false;    

function manualSelect(item) {
  if ($('manual' + item) == false) {
    $('manual' + item) = true;
  } else {
    $('manual' + item) = false;
  }
}
```

I know this is stupid, it's just to set the example.

Here's the full script:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ers54s9/5/

Comment: Given that `$('manual' + item)` will *never* equal `false`, aside from the fact that it can not be *set* to `true` or `false`, I'm not sure what you're attempting to achieve

Comment: Change $manualColor or $manualAnimal to oposite true/false, based on the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, of course:

```js
var manual = {
  "Color": false,
  "Animal": false,
};

$("button").on("click", function() {
  var item = $(this).data("select");
  manual[item] = !manual[item];
  console.info(manual);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="colorbutton" class="button red"  data-select="Color">Colors</button>
    <button type="button" id="animalbutton" class="button red" data-select="Animal">Animals</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. And if I need to change the button class based on click (bellow manual[item] = !manual[item];) based on it being true or false? Let's say if true add class blue, if false add class orange.

Comment: Then you would do 
`if (manual[item]) { 
  $(this).addClass("blue").removeClass("orange"); 
} else {
  $(this).addClass("orange").removeClass("blue");
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can access properties of an object by text, eg:

```
flags["animal"] = true;
```

which you can also access as:

```
flags.animal = true;
```

so put all the "variables" that you want to toggle onto another variable, eg:

```js
var flags = {};

function toggleFlag(item) {
  flags[item] = !flags[item];


  console.log("color: " + flags.color)
  console.log("animal: " + flags.animal)
  console.log(flags)
}

toggleFlag("test")

$(".button").click(function() {
  toggleFlag($(this).data("flag"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button" data-flag='color'>Colors</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" data-flag='animal'>Animals</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. And if I need to change the button class based on click (bellow flags[item] = !flags[item];) based on it being true or false? Let's say if true add class blue, if false add class orange.

Comment: `$(this).addClass(flags[item] ? "blue" : "orange");`

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS

```
<button ng-click="manual()">Click me!</button>
```

```js
$scope.manualColor = true;

$scope.manual = function () {
  $scope.manualColor = false;
}
```

Comment: As useful as this may be, the OP has given no indication that they are using Angular.

Comment: As you can guess, my programming skills are quite lacking. Angular is way of my reach. But thanks anyway.